# Why aren't the right and left floats stacking together? Where does the space between them come from?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I bet this is probably basic stuff, I've just never come across it before. So, the code:

- I've got a  h1 followed by a p, followed by the same thing twice. So it goes h1 + p + h1 + p + h1 + p ;
- I've floated the h1's to the left, with a 29% width ;
- I've floated the p's to the right, width a 69% width ;

My question:

Why are the h1's not stacking up together? I notice the first two are. Why isn't the third one doing the same? Why is it top-aligned with the second paragraph (notice that if you change the p's bottom margin, the h1 follows it)? What am I missing about float behavior?

Here's the example at tinkerbin : http://tinkerbin.com/IUVovfjM

Here's the code:

```
<head>
<style>
h1, p, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font: inherit;
}

h1{
   float: right; 
   width: 29%; 
   background-color: lightblue;
   }

p{
   float: left; 
   width: 69%; 
   background-color: indianred;
   } 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>This Is The Title</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum badum badum baei.A primeira exposição apresenta, através de elementos       multimédia, a evolução do dinheiro, com especial referência ao espaço que hoje é Portugal. A   exposição termina com um núcleo dedicado à produção das notas, em que materiais e máquinas ilustram as diferentes fases da vida da nota, desde a sua concepção artística até à sua impressão, assim como os principais elementos de segurança que lhe estão associados.</p>
<h1>This Is The Title</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum badum badum baei.A primeira exposição apresenta, através de elementos multimédia, a evolução do dinheiro, com especial referência ao espaço que hoje é Portugal. A exposição termina com um núcleo dedicado à produção das notas, em que materiais e máquinas ilustram as diferentes fases da vida da nota, desde a sua concepção artística até à sua impressão, assim como os principais elementos de segurança que lhe estão associados.</p>
<h1>This Is The Title</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum badum badum baei.A primeira exposição apresenta, através de elementos multimédia, a evolução do dinheiro, com especial referência ao espaço que hoje é Portugal. A exposição termina com um núcleo dedicado à produção das notas, em que materiais e máquinas ilustram as diferentes fases da vida da nota, desde a sua concepção artística até à sua impressão, assim como os principais elementos de segurança que lhe estão associados.</p>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why?

Taken from CSS specification:

1. "A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the **current line**." - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats
2. "The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the source document." - item #5 at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position

So, it is the **order** of your HTML elements which is doing this.

Don't change your CSS, play only with the headers and paragraphs, and you will get the "why": http://tinkerbin.com/xex2Pykn

To achieve the stacking you want, without changing the CSS, you may try this:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum badum badum baei.A primeira exposição apresenta, através de elementos multimédia, a evolução do dinheiro, com especial referência ao espaço que hoje é Portugal. A exposição termina com um núcleo dedicado à produção das notas, em que materiais e máquinas ilustram as diferentes fases da vida da nota, desde a sua concepção artística até à sua impressão, assim como os principais elementos de segurança que lhe estão associados.</p>
<h1>This Is The Title</h1>
<h1>This Is The Title</h1>
<h1>This Is The Title</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum badum badum baei.A primeira exposição apresenta, através de elementos multimédia, a evolução do dinheiro, com especial referência ao espaço que hoje é Portugal. A exposição termina com um núcleo dedicado à produção das notas, em que materiais e máquinas ilustram as diferentes fases da vida da nota, desde a sua concepção artística até à sua impressão, assim como os principais elementos de segurança que lhe estão associados.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum badum badum baei.A primeira exposição apresenta, através de elementos multimédia, a evolução do dinheiro, com especial referência ao espaço que hoje é Portugal. A exposição termina com um núcleo dedicado à produção das notas, em que materiais e máquinas ilustram as diferentes fases da vida da nota, desde a sua concepção artística até à sua impressão, assim como os principais elementos de segurança que lhe estão associados.</p>
```

There are several other possible solutions, changing the CSS and/or the HTML structure.

Comment: Hadn't yet read your answer. Let me play a little, I'll come back in a  few minutes.

Comment: But why do the first two `h1`'s stack together. Why does the third one line up with the second `p`? I'm still finding this difficult to understand.

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo: I am learning too. Just found another piece of the spec that explains it. I will add to the answer. - Now it is explained!

Comment: The second point explains it all. Hey, thanks for your interest in the question, and thanks for taking the time to share the knowledge ;). Marked this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://tinkerbin.com/wMLrXlfQ

Add `clear: both;` to the `h1` and it would appear properly.